# Creating a substring that ends at a certain character vb.net

Tags: vb.net, substring

I am working with files and I need to pull a substring to insert into a database. Each underscore is the break point for the file and I need to make code that will create a substring that ends at an underscore

Here are what the file names look like

```
20150225_1291223_FO_8a168549-a520-4f93-b607
20150226_88959_FO_1a2c912c-a4e5-459a-992b-a75991e63df1~20150326_151437
```

As you can see the values "1291223" and "88959" so I cannot just hard code a start and end point for the substring

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't properly error-checked, but you get the idea. Use `Split` and separate by "_".

```
Dim sFilename As String = "20150225_1291223_FO_8a168549-a520-4f93-b607"
Dim sSplitUp() As String = sFilename.Split("_")
MessageBox.Show(sSplitUp(1))
```